# Detecting Touch on WebGL Canvas only in threejs

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am working on a threejs application that should take input from **HTML buttons** and has **Raycast Detection** on touch in threeJS as well,

The problem I am facing is when the user presses the HTML button the Raycast is happening as well that is because my Raycast code runs on the event **'ontouchstart'**

This is unwanted behaviour for what I am trying to do.

I have tried using 'ontouchend' to detect Raycast instead, but that also doesn't solve the problem, I need some way where the Raycast code never runs if a button was every pressed.

The Raycast Code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener("touchstart",this._onTouchStart,false);

}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.addEventListener("touchstart",this._onTouchStart,false);
}

_onTouchStart = (event) =>{
    event.clientX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    event.clientY = event.touches[0].pageY;
    const mouse = {
        x: (event.clientX / this.props.gl.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
        y: -(event.clientY / this.props.gl.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1
    }
    this.props.raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse,this.props.camera);


    if(this.objects.current == null) return null;

    const intersects = this.props.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.objects.current.children[1].children );

    /* **  */
}
```

The ThreeJS Canvas I am using React Three Fiber

```
    <Canvas>
      <Component />
      <CameraController />
      <EnvironmentSettings />
    </Canvas>
    <HTMLButtons />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the event listener to the `window` element if you don't want it to capture the entire window. Be more specific with what you assign the listeners to. Perhaps you should add the event on the canvas instead, so when you click the button, the canvas doesn't need to know about it:

`canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",this._onTouchStart,false);`